# Google maps streetview javascript API - prevent zoom when not in focus?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Please see my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fXu5d/52/

When I'm typing in the input box, if I enter a hyphen or a plus, the google street view zooms out and in!  Even when it's not got focus!  Is there any way to disable this unless focus is on the streetview?

```
var panoramaOptions = {
    disableDefaultUI: true
};

panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), panoramaOptions);
```

Comment: Bug reported.  I'll update this article if and when I receive a response.

Comment: Issue in the issue tracker: [Issue 11517: Street view zooms out and in when pressing - and + in an input field (or anywhere else on the page!)](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11517)